# How to append one column to an existing array column in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

append columnA to an existing array-type column B

```
select
string_column_A,
array_column_B,
append(array_column_B, string_column_A) as AB
from onetable;
```

To be more accurate, I should say "set" instead of "array" above, since I expect no duplicates. But the duplication here is not a big deal.

What's the best way to make this in Hive? I have checked the hive documentation, but cannot find any relevant information to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `select concat("A",concat_ws("",array('B','C')));`
If you want separator `,` then  use below statement.

```
select concat_ws(",","A",concat_ws(",",array('B','C')));
```

Comment: This is a brilliant idea! But the question is now it's not an array any more:      select array_contains(array(concat_ws(",","A",concat_ws(",",array('B','C'))),'B');   returns "false".

Comment: Is there any way to unique the array elements?  select concat_ws(",","A",concat_ws(",",array('A','C'))) will give [["A", "A", "C"]], wish to get [["A", "C"]].

Comment: Try collect_set(col)
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Answer (score 0):

I think the best alternative is to use Klout's brickhouse JAR that contains the ArrayUnionUDF, which returns an array, works not only for string arrays and will also cancel duplicates.
The github page is [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) While the code for the UDF itself is [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayUnionUDF.java)

Usage example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION array_union AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayUnionUDF';
SELECT array_union(array(string_column_A), array_column_B) AS combined_columns
```